# Compare URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function like this:

```
if ( document.url!= 'search.php') {
    window.location = 'search.php' 
}
```

This is not working; it seems I may need to check if URL string contains 'search.php' - or is there another way I can do this check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're searching for `indexOf`. Note that it's not `document.url`, but `document.URL`:

```
if (document.URL.indexOf('search.php') == -1) {
    window.location = 'search.php';
}
```

**Note**: This will also match the following:

http://www.domain.com/search.php
http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=search.php&test
http://www.domain.com/search.php/non-search.php
http://www.domain.com/non-search.php#search.php

**Extra note**: Why are you doing this? If people have javascript disabled, they will never get forwarded. Maybe you're searching for the `301` or `302` header?

Comment: That is what I wanted, but you have a good point; when users click on a search input field, which is persistent in the header, I want them to automatically be forward to a search page where there is a AJAX post that displays search suggestions as they type.  A better way of doing this then?

Comment: @KickingLettuce You could heavily style an `<a>` tag or a `<button>` to look like your search field, on all the pages that aren't `search.php`, so when you click, the browser would just act like it was any other `<a>` tag. Personally I think you should have a dynamic search input box on all pages instead, though.

Comment: I do technically have the search box on all pages.

Comment: @KickingLettuce But you shouldn't forward users who click it - why not just make it dynamic right there, like most websites? (Facebook for instance).

Comment: A drop down box would be ideal yes. I dont know how to do that yet, but good reason to learn.  Currently, the Search Suggestions simply use up the main `<div>` of the body of the page. Ok thanks for your help..

Answer (score 2):

I always use this.

```
if (window.location.href != 'search.php') {//get the current url
        window.location.href = 'search.php' //redirect
    }
```

Try any of these

```
- alert(document.URL)

- alert(Window.location.href)

- alert(document.location.href)

- alert(window.location.pathname)
```

for creating dropdown with links -:Put this in the success part of your ajax

```
            var data=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            var alldata;
            for(var  i=0;i< data.length;i++)
            {
                alldata += "<a id='some_id' onclick='myFunction(this.id);' href='whatever#' class='link'>"+data[i][0]+"</a><hr>";
            }
            //data[i][0]-->this depends on your json text.
       document.getElementById('your_input_field_id or div_id').innerHTML = alldata;
```

Comment: KickingLettuce:check ,i have done the same thing with autocomplete...might help you